# AWS AMI Cleanup w/Ansible iterate through results array

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I have a previous task that creates weekly backups, labeling them with the server name followed by a date/time tag. The goal of this job is to go in behind it and clean up the old AMI backups, leaving only the last 3. The `ec2_ami_find` task works fine, but it could also return empty results for some servers and I'd like the deregister task to handle that.

The error I'm getting is pretty generic:

> fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
>       "failed": true,
>       "msg": "The conditional check 'item.ec2_ami_find.exists' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional
>   (item.ec2_ami_find.exists): 'dict object' has no attribute
>   'ec2_ami_find'\n\nThe error appears to have been in
>   '/root/ansible/ec2-backups-purge/roles/first_acct/tasks/main.yml': line 25,
>   column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact
>   syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name:
>   Deregister old backups\n  ^ here\n"

The playbook task reads as follows:

```
---
- name: Find old backups
  tags: always
  ec2_ami_find:
    owner: self
    aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    ami_tags:
      Name: "{{ item }}-weekly-*"
    sort: name
    sort_order: descending
    sort_start: 3
  with_items:
    - server-01
    - server-02
    - server-win-01
    - downloads
  register: stale_amis

- name: Deregister old backups
  tags: always
  ec2_ami:
    aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    image_id: "{{ item.ami_id }}"
    delete_snapshot: True
    state: absent
  with_items:
    - "{{ stale_amis.results }}"
```

Snippet of one of the results returns:

```
"results": [
    {
        "ami_id": "ami-zzzzzzz",
        "architecture": "x86_64",
        "block_device_mapping": {
            "/dev/xvda": {
                "delete_on_termination": true,
                "encrypted": false,
                "size": 200,
                "snapshot_id": "snap-xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "volume_type": "gp2"
            }
        },
        "creationDate": "2017-08-01T15:26:11.000Z",
        "description": "Weekly backup via Ansible",
        "hypervisor": "xen",
        "is_public": false,
        "location": "111111111111/server-01.example.com-20170801152611Z",
        "name": "server-01.example.com-20170801152611Z",
        "owner_id": "111111111111",
        "platform": null,
        "root_device_name": "/dev/xvda",
        "root_device_type": "ebs",
        "state": "available",
        "tags": {
            "Name": "server-01-weekly-20170801152611Z",
            "Type": "weekly"
        },
        "virtualization_type": "hvm"
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt your attempt:

```
  with_items:
    - "{{ stale_amis.results }}"
```

because `ec2_ami_find` put results into own `results` field. So the first AMI for first server will be `stale_amis.results[0].results[0].ami_id`

I advice to reduce original `stale_amis` to required list and loop over it. For example you can use `json_query` filter:

```
- ec2_ami:
    aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    image_id: "{{ item }}"
    delete_snapshot: True
    state: absent
  with_items: "{{ stale_amis | json_query('results[].results[].ami_id') }}"
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!

Note for others, had to install package `python2-jmespath`